# Rogue and Investigator multi-class—Do Studied Combat and Sneak Attack stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, sneak-attack, stacking

I am building a level 8 character that has 4 levels of [Rogue Unchained](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/) and 4 levels of [Investigator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/).

The classes have a similar, but not identical, feature:

> Studied Strike (Ex) - At 4th level, an investigator can choose to make a studied strike against the target of his studied combat as a free action, upon successfully hitting his studied target with a melee attack, to deal additional damage. The damage is 1d6 at 4th level, and increases by 1d6 for every 2 levels thereafter (to a maximum of 9d6 at 20th level). The damage of studied strike is precision damage and is not multiplied on a critical hit; creatures that are immune to sneak attacks are also immune to studied strike.
>
> If the investigator’s attack used a weapon that deals nonlethal damage (like a sap, whip, or an unarmed strike), he may choose to have the additional damage from studied strike be nonlethal damage instead of lethal damage. If the investigator chose to make an attack with a lethal weapon instead deal nonlethal damage (with the usual –4 penalty), the studied strike damage may also deal nonlethal damage.
>
> The investigator must be able to see the target well enough to pick out a vital spot and must be able to reach such a spot. An investigator cannot use studied strike against a creature with concealment.

and:

> Sneak Attack - If a rogue can catch an opponent when he is unable to defend himself effectively from her attack, she can strike a vital spot for extra damage.
>
> The rogue’s attack deals extra damage anytime her target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not), or when the rogue flanks her target. This extra damage is 1d6 at 1st level, and increases by 1d6 every 2 rogue levels thereafter. Ranged attacks can count as sneak attacks only if the target is within 30 feet. This additional damage is precision damage and is not multiplied on a critical hit.
>
> With a weapon that deals nonlethal damage (such as a sap, unarmed strike, or whip), a rogue can make a sneak attack that deals nonlethal damage instead of lethal damage. She cannot use a weapon that deals lethal damage to deal nonlethal damage in a sneak attack—not even with the usual –4 penalty.
>
> The rogue must be able to see the target well enough to pick out a vital spot and must be able to reach such a spot. A rogue cannot sneak attack while striking a creature with total concealment.

Assuming all other requirements are met, do these two bonuses to damage stack with one another?

Comment: I'm curious what would make you think they *wouldn't* combine. For example, does it seem overpowered to you or your GM? Or is it just the similarity of the descriptions?

Comment: No, I thought they would combine, but I was confirming because I'm not super familiar with the deeper pathfinder rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A [rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/)/[investigator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/) that meets both abilities' requirements can benefit from both [sneak attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/Rogue-unchained/#TOC-Sneak-Attack) and [studied strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/Investigator/#TOC-Studied-Strike-Ex-)

[Hybrid Classes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/) on Parent Classes says

> Each one of the following classes lists two classes that it draws upon to form the basis of its theme. While a character can multiclass with these parent classes, this usually results in redundant abilities. Such abilities don't stack unless specified.

However, unlike, for example, a [hunter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter/) 5 who gains the extraordinary ability [woodland stride](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/Hunter/#TOC-Woodland-Stride-Ex-) then multiclasses so as to become also a [ranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger) 7 and gains again the extraordinary ability [woodland stride](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Ranger/#TOC-Woodland-Stride-Ex-), the [unchained rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/)'s extraordinary ability [sneak attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/Rogue-unchained/#TOC-Sneak-Attack) and the [investigator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/)'s extraordinary ability [studied strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/Investigator/#TOC-Studied-Strike-Ex-) have different names and effects despite sharing similar (yet not identical) language.

The special abilities sneak attack and studied strike are different abilities, and their effects don't so much *stack* (as bonuses typically do—see [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/) for the definition of *Bonus*) but merely combine for greater effect. Thus, if everything's going his way, a rogue 4/investigator 4 *via* this combination of special abilities can deal an extra +3d6 points of precision damage.